# iOS: Recurrence/Future Payment through PayPal

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I want to implement automatically `recurring` payment (customers are automatically charged monthly on a particular date). Using [paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK), i can perform single payment but I need to implement Future `payments` in my app so user only have to enter his payment detail one time. And every other time Amount is transfer automatically on a particular date or a particular period of months.
Someone please suggest how can I develop such functionality in my app so that user don't have to enter his Credit card detail again and again and amount will be deducted automatically from user's account.

Comment: I guess Paypal has already provided the document for Future payments.  https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_mobile.md#obtain-an-application-correlation-id. All it does is obtain client metadata from Paypal and send back it to server which you can use it to initiate the future payment based on recurring date provided.

Comment: thanks from this link half of my work is done, but please tell me where i have to mention amount and month duration

Comment: Amount and duration information should be pass-on to the server and your server should trigger future payments. This should not be done on client side. Once you get these information from client you need to pass these to server.

Comment: One last ques how do i call PayPalProfileSharingDelegate and PayPalFuturePaymentDelegate at the same time

Comment: I guess you want be able to call both delegate at same time because if in order to require to be delegate you need to present either of the vc - PayPalFuturePaymentViewController or PayPalProfileSharingViewController at the same time. But of your intention is to take consent for profile as well as future payments then you can use only PayPalProfileSharingViewController and include future payment in scope of consent using kPayPalOAuth2ScopeFuturePayments;